# Read and Save Image from excel file from FoxPro

Tags: excel, automation, foxpro

Im using Visual Foxpro 9.

I have an Excel File with Item List and Pictures below each Item.
Each Item occupy One row and the Picture occupies 3 rows.

I was able to save the Text for Each Item/Row but have no idea on how to save the Pictures below each item. Pls guide me in the right direction.

Thanks,
Herbert

Comment: What have you tried so far? This isn't a do my job\homework site.

Comment: Thanks Alan. So you got up on the wrong side of the bed when you answered this?

Comment: Have you tried recording a macro where you copy the picture, so you can see how Excel lets you address it?

Comment: Herbert, I think Alan's comment is fair. I think you will not be able to use the OOTB import here. I think you are going to have to use low level file I/O (http://fox.wikis.com/wc.dll?Wiki~LowLevelFileFunctions) to read the file and decompose it to get the embedded graphics - the problem with this approach is figuring out how to relate the picture with the correct row in the spreadsheet. Some samples of your work or the data would be helpful. Nelson.

Answer (score 0):

You can copy them clipboard and then save using something like gdiPlusx.FromClipboard. ie:

```
local ix, oExcel
oExcel = Createobject('Excel.Application')
With oExcel
  .WorkBooks.Open("c:\My Folder\MyExcel.xlsx")

  With .ActiveWorkBook.ActiveSheet
    For ix = 1 To .Shapes.Count
        .Shapes(m.ix).CopyPicture()
        * Save the picture in clipboard
    Endfor
  Endwith
Endwith
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the code that Cetin suggested above gets the picture file for you, **DO NOT** try to store it into a Data Table.

Instead store it as a Image File (JPG, BMP, etc.) within a directory on your server's drive. And then store the Path to it within your Data Table.

Then, when needed, your VFP application can 'know' where and how to acquire the picture and use it as needed without introducing Data Table problems.

Good Luck